# Can this javascript be written more efficiently?

Tags: javascript

I'm using these two functions to control the height of separate drops on a navigation bar. It's working, but I'm sure it could be written as one function ... i just don't know how. Thanks in advance for any suggestions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function nav() {
  $('.nav li').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('ul.item1_sub').show();
    $(this).find('ul.item1_sub').stop().animate({
      height: '145px',
      opacity: '100'
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 200,
      easing: 'easeInSine'
    })
  }, function () {
    $(this).find('ul.item1_sub').stop().animate({
      height: '0px',
      opacity: '0'
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 100,
      easing: 'easeInCirc'
    })
  });
};
$(document).ready(function () {
  nav();
});

function nav2() {
  $('.nav li').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('ul.item2_sub').show();
    $(this).find('ul.item2_sub').stop().animate({
      height: '170px',
      opacity: '100'
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 200,
      easing: 'easeInSine'
    })
  }, function () {
    $(this).find('ul.item2_sub').stop().animate({
      height: '0px',
      opacity: '0'
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 100,
      easing: 'easeInCirc'
    })
  });
};
$(document).ready(function () {
  nav2();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using in the same context $(this) more than once, every time you use the jQuery function $() for the same element you waste resources and time. You should stick it into a variabile and refer to that variabile from that point on.

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Also this is used twice:

```
$(this).find('ul.item2_sub')
```

Should be

```
var $this = $(this);
var $items = $this.find('ul.item2_sub');

$items.show();
$items.stop().animate();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like this without knowing what your page looks like

```
$(function() {
     $('.nav li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('ul.item1_sub, ul.item2_sub').slideDown();
},function(){
    $(this).find('ul.item1_sub, ul.item2_sub').slideUp();
});        
});
```

Comment: I did part of it. Then I felt bad. Meh. Then 5 other people wrote answers. So oh well. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are only a few values different between the two functions as far as I can see. If you really want to refactor these into one function, you could define the function

```
function nav(item, height) {
  $('.nav li').hover(function () {
    $(this).find(item).show();
    $(this).find(item).stop().animate({
      height: height,
      opacity: '100'
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 200,
      easing: 'easeInSine'
    })
  }, function () {
    $(this).find(item).stop().animate({
      height: '0px',
      opacity: '0'
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 100,
      easing: 'easeInCirc'
    })
  });
};
```

Then call it with the appropriate parameters

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    nav('ul.item1_sub', '145px');
    nav('ul.item2_sub', '170px');
});
```

You could also add more parameters if necessary.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  this makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's `slideUp` and `slideDown` instead of reinventing the wheel.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.nav li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul.item1_sub, ul.item2_sub').slideDown();
    },function(){
        $(this).find('ul.item1_sub, ul.item2_sub').slideUp();
    });

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Laa7G/

Answer (score 0):

Just generalizing, not checked for accuracy:

```
function nav(item, height){
$('.nav li').hover(function() {
$(this).find(item).show(); 
     $(this).find(item).stop().animate({height:height, opacity: '100'},{queue:false, duration:200, easing: 'easeInSine'})
        }, function() {
     $(this).find(item).stop().animate({height: '0px',opacity: '0'},{queue:false, duration:100, easing: 'easeInCirc'}) 
      });
  };
  $(document).ready(function() {
    nav('ul.item1.sub, '145px');
    nav('ul.item2.sub', '170px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rewritten version that should give you what you wish for :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onMouseOver() {
   var self = $(this), 
       item1_sub = self.find('ul.item1_sub'), 
       item2_sub = self.find('ul.item2_sub'),
       animOptions = { queue: false, duration: 200, easing: 'easeInSine' };

    item1_sub.show().stop().animate({ height: '145px', opacity: '100' }, animOptions);
    item2_sub.show().stop().animate({ height: '170px', opacity: '100' }, animOptions);

}

function onMouseOut() {
    $(this).find('ul.item1_sub, ul.item2_sub').stop().animate({ height: '0px', opacity: '0' }, { queue: false, duration: 100, easing: 'easeInCirc' });
}


function onDomReady() { 
  $('.nav li').hover(onMouseOver, onMouseOut); 
}


$(onDomReady);

</script>
```